# How can call selectItemAt: function at collectionView(_:didSelectItemAt:)?

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview

I have a UICollectionView and, the collecitonView has enough items.
When 5th cell was selected by touching, I wanna cancel the 5th cell selection and back to the last selected cell.
The UICollectionView has like below options.

```
var lastSelectedIndexPath: IndexPath
let collectionView = UICollectionView(frame: .zero, collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewFlowLayout())
collectionView.allowsMultipleSelection = false
collectionView.allowsSelection = true

...

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    if shouldRollBackSelection {
        // just test code
        collectionView.selectItem(at: lastSelectedIndexPath, animated: false, scrollPosition: UICollectionView.ScrollPosition())
    } else {
        lastSelectedIndexPath = indexPath
    }
}
```

If collectionView.selectItem(...) function is called, the last selected cell's isSelected property's didSet will be called twice.
First call is false to true, and Second call is true to false. The result, the last selected cell's isSelected property is false.

I want to rollback the selection of UICollectionView's Cell. I mean that I want to do not allow selection of speciific cell.

Comment: SO what's the challenge that you are facing now?

Comment: I didn't get your question what specific functionality you want to perform ?

Comment: @Abhishek I edited the question. It's the last line.

Comment: @KarthickRamesh Oh, sorry. The challenge is last line. I added.

Comment: So basically, Let's say there are 8 cells in the UICollectionView. Then you need something like 4th and 8th cells should not be allowed to be selected by the user right?

Comment: @KarthickRamesh Yes, right. That's the perfect expectation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make user interaction disabled for those cells which you don't want selection

```
 override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier, for: indexPath)
    if indexPath.row == 4 {
        cell.isUserInteractionEnabled = false
    }
    return cell

  }
```

Answer (score 1):

It's not the best way but you can add a `guard` before setting the last index to prevent duplicate calls:

```
guard lastSelectedIndexPath != indexPath else { return }
```

Comment: Duplicate call doesn't matter I think. I edited my question.

Answer (score 1):

It is better deactivate selection for cell in cellForItemAt overload with:

```
     func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "YourCel", for: indexPath) as! UpperCollectionViewCell
        if indexPath.row == 4 {
           cell.isUserInteractionEnabled = false
        }
        return cell
    }
```